# How to append data to an existing file in databricks with python?

Tags: python, databricks

I am trying to append data in DBFS with python but it is throwing error, can some one help on this

```
#write a file to DBFS using python i/o apis
with open("/dbfs/tmp/test_dbfs.txt", 'a') as f:
  f.write("Apache Spark is awesome!\n")
  f.write("End of example!")
```

Error

```
[Errno 95] Operation not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation in Databricks about Local File API:

https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html?_ga=2.77331157.1317975239.1613139339-582475836.1531997543#local-file-api-limitations

There is one limitation from runtime 6.0: **it does not support random writes**

Please refer the documentation.